# how can I get data from a child component to a parent component if there are several input fields in the child component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

The parent component has data that I want to pass to the child component. For example, I created such a component with data.
**Parent component**

```
<template>
         
   <NameUser :data="userData"></NameUser>
   <div>first name: {{ userData.firstName }}</div>
   <div>last name: {{ userData.lastName }}</div>
 
</template>

<script setup>
    
    import {ref} from 'vue'
    import NameUser from '../components/NameUser.vue';
    const userData = ref({
        firstName: 'testName',
        lastName: 'testLastName'
    })

</script>
```

In the child component, I receive this data and will have to pass it back to the parent component after changing it.
**Child component**

```
<template>

    <label>First name</label>
    <input :value="data.firstName" @input="changeData">

    <label>Last name</label>
    <input :value="data.lastName" @input="changeData">

</template>

<script setup>

    const props = defineProps({
        data:Object
    })

    function changeData(){}

</script>
```

Help to implement the changeData function. Please tell me if it is necessary to use the computed property to avoid re-rendering.

Answer (score 0):

[SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

You can use a separate reactive object inside `NameUser` to update it from inputs and synchronize it with a model value. That way you can add any additional inputs without declaring any extra variables.

Also your `changeData` doesn't receive any extra parameter to distinguish different props in the user object. Use `v-model` on inputs instead. Otherwise it's unnecessarily complicated.

NameUser.vue

```
<script setup>

    import {reactive, watch} from 'vue';
    const props = defineProps({
        modelValue: Object
    });

    const value = reactive({});
    const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue']);
    
    // 2-way binding - watch for the prop changes
    watch(() => props.modelValue, data => Object.assign(value, data), {immediate:true});
    // create a copy of value so the above watch would be triggered
    watch(value, value => emit('update:modelValue', {...value}));

</script>
<template>

    <label>First name</label>
    <input v-model="value.firstName" >

    <label>Last name</label>
    <input v-model="value.lastName" >

</template>
```

Parent.vue:

```
<script setup>
    
    import {ref} from 'vue'
    import NameUser from './NameUser.vue';
    const userData = ref({
        firstName: 'testName',
        lastName: 'testLastName'
    })

</script>

<template>

   <NameUser v-model="userData"></NameUser>
   <div>first name: {{ userData.firstName }}</div>
   <div>last name: {{ userData.lastName }}</div>

    <br/>
   <div>Check 2-way binding:</div>
   <NameUser v-model="userData"></NameUser>
 
</template>
```